# Running an Access Macro with Task Scheduler but want to hide Access whn it Runs. Not See Access Open and Close

Tags: ms-access, task, scheduler

I have created an `Access Database` with `Queries` and a `Macro` to manually run the queries when opened. I then set up a `Task Schedule` to open and run my Access `Macro`.

The issue is that I have it set to run every time I login to my computer but the issue is I would rather not see the Access Database open and close.  Is there a way to run it in the background without even noticing it running?

Comment: If you just rum some queries, a powershell script ,maybe more reliable.. If dtill want to use ms access run in different user context to make it not accessible or just minimize app window.. Code needs to have all errors catchted and no msgboxes should appear or the app will halt.

Answer (score 0):

You may check the security options of your task to see "Run whether the user is logged in or not" option is selected.

As an alternative approach,  you may also consider to run your macro from the Timer event of a form in Access.

BR,  Caglar